# Barometer barometric pressue

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

the barometric pressure and height on earth are 10^5 pa and 760 mm respectively . Then what is barometric height if it is taken at moom . 
I think at moon the gravity will decrease then pressure should also decrease and according to that height should also change .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moon doesn't have an atmosphere (or only a [very tenuous and exotic one](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LADEE/news/lunar-atmosphere.html#.VnGUabEleUk)) therefore you cannot use a conventional [barometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer) pressure gauge to measure altitude above the surface.

A barometric measurement like the 760 mm you mention is the height of a column of mercury that can be supported by atmospheric pressure near sea level on Earth. On the moon this would be very close to zero.

The atmospheric pressure on the moon at night is $3 \times 10^{-15}$ bar according to [NASA](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/moonfact.html)

This would be something like 0.000000000002 mm

It would be more interesting to take your barometer to Saturn's moon [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)#Atmosphere)

Comment: But there could be pressure due to gravity and collision of water molecules

Comment: @user101522: No water molecules have been detected, only *"an infinitesimal amount of ... helium, argon, and possibly neon, ammonia, methane and carbon dioxide."*

Answer (score 0):

The "height" you refer to is not a distance up, or altitude.  It is the height of a column of mercury needed to balance the local atmospheric pressure.

Take a glass tube, closed at one end (a tall, skinny glass).  Fill it with mercury, cover the open end, invert it, place the temporarily closed end in a mercury-filled vessel, and unplug the end.  The mercury level in the tube will fall until the height of the column is around 760 mm.  As the weather changes, you will see this level change, showing the changes in local atmospheric pressure.

Suppose you want to use the same device to check if your moon habitat is losing pressure.  The equation that determines the mercury column height ($h$) contains the term $\rho g h$, where $\rho$ is the density of mercury, and $g$ is the local acceleration of gravity.

Since $g$ on the moon is about $\frac16$ the gravity on earth, your lunar habitat barometer would need to be around $6 \times$ taller, or about $4.5$ metres high.

Of course, if you go outside, the barometric pressure would be zero.